# How to change link text from jquery function on click event

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I stuck in very simple situation.
I have a link that execute ajax call and on success I need to change clicked link text or color.

```
foreach (var m in Model.GroupPosts){
...
@Html.ActionLink("Vote up", "Vote", "GroupPost", new { groupPostId = m.GroupPostId }, new{@class="vote-up"})
                @Html.ActionLink("Vote down", "Vote", "GroupPost", new { groupPostId = m.GroupPostId }, new { @class = "vote-down" })
}

$('.vote-up').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (html) {
                    alert("voted up");
                    e.target.text("New link text");
                }
            });
        });
```

I can't change clicked link text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$(e.target).text("New link text");
```

Also you may keep a reference of the clicked `button/Link` outside of the `AJAX` call and then you may use it inside your `success` callback; like this:

```
$('.vote-up').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('href'),
    btn = $(this); // <-- reference the Button/Link
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (html) {
            alert("voted up");
            btn.text("New link text"); // <-- Use that referenced jQuery Object
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

And the pure javascript way:

```
 e.target.innerHTML = "New link text"
```

`e.target` is an element, not a jQuery object, so it doesn't have the `text()` method you are attempting to use. You can either use the element's `innerHTML` property, or wrap the element in jQuery to give you access to `text()` as WereWolf demonstrates.